# I want to use activity instead of fragments in navigation activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer, android-fragmentactivity

As I create navigation activity I always use fragments.
But now I want to use activity instead of that.
Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can, 
just start the new activity with an Intent :

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondScreen.class);
StartActivity(i);
```